# Upgrade build gradle cause Gradle’s new variant-aware dependency management error

Tags: android, build.gradle, dependency-management

I have an Android project it works well in build gradle 2.3.3, when I use build gradle 3.0.1 I meet some build error. Here is the error build.gradle, its project name is A.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: '../Localization/localize.gradle'
apply plugin: 'maven'
......
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode buildVersionCode
    versionName buildVersionNumber

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-std=c++11"
        }
    }
    ndk{
        // Specifies the ABI configurations of your native
        // libraries Gradle should build and package with your APK.
        /*abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a',
        'arm64-v8a'*/
        abiFilters 'x86','armeabi-v7a'
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'

    // Set build time-stamp and version number
    buildConfigField  "String", "sProjectBuildTime", "\"${buildTimeStamp}\"";
    buildConfigField  "String", "sProjectVersionNumber", "\"${buildVersionNumber}\"";

    ......
}
```

It apply from a localize.gradle, this is the localize.gradle content

```
// import legacy ANT tasks: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/using
gradle-to-bootstrap-your-legacy.html for XSLT based localization
ant.projectName = 'A'
ant.importBuild '../../Tools/Localization/localize.xml'
// expose legacy ANT task as GradleBuild task
task gradleLocalize(type: GradleBuild) { GradleBuild antBuild ->
    antBuild.buildFile = 'build.gradle'
    antBuild.tasks = ['ant2gradleLocalize']
}

// automatically run localization GradleBuild task when the AndroidManifest gets checked during the build
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith('check')) {
        if (task.name.endsWith('DebugManifest') || 
task.name.endsWith('ReleaseManifest')) {
            task.dependsOn gradleLocalize
        }
    }
}
```

And the error information is 
A problem occurred evaluating project ':A'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
>   Due to a limitation of Gradle’s new variant-aware dependency management, loading the Android Gradle plugin in different class loaders leads to a build error.
>        This can occur when the buildscript classpaths that contain the Android Gradle plugin in sub-projects, or included projects in the case of composite builds, are set differently.
>        To resolve this issue, add the Android Gradle plugin to only the buildscript classpath of the top-level build.gradle file.
>        In the case of composite builds, also make sure the build script classpaths that contain the Android Gradle plugin are identical across the main and included projects.
>        If you are using a version of Gradle that has fixed the issue, you can disable this check by setting android.enableBuildScriptClasspathCheck=false in the gradle.properties file.
>        To learn more about this issue, go to https://d.android.com/r/tools/buildscript-classpath-check.html.

I find the plugin name com.android.library in whole project it just appear once, I guess maybe project A's build.gradle and localize.grandle has a circular dependence, Can anyone help? I am blocked by this for a long time. Thanks!